# How to remove the hidden tags from innerHTML string

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML tables with data. There are some columns which are hidden, based on report generation. 
I am generating an Excel file from these table. For generating the Excel file, I have to provide the `innerHTML` data to the Excel function. The issue is that, `innerHTML` data contains hidden tags as well.

This results in Excel file showing the hidden column data. Is there a way I can remove the hidden tags' data?

Comment: Can you just remove all child elements and then get the innerHTML?

Comment: Posting a sample code will help.  Essentially, in plain JS, you can iterate over DOM elements and exclude the `element type='hidden'` elements.

Comment: the solution is pretty straightforward, have you tried solving it on your own? if yes please post what you have tried in your question.

Comment: You should manipulate the DOM elements first, then get the innerHTML. Attempting to manipulate HTML as text is not pleasant. Do you have an example of how the columns are hidden?

Comment: Did the underlying solution work for you?

Comment: @ArinCool—the OP hasn't tagged the question with jQuery, nor used it in the OP.

Comment: Yes, I know. Its just that using JQuery the code becomes much simpler as compared to native JS. Hence added the same.

Comment: @ArinCool—it's impossible to substantiate that assumption given that you don't know how the cells are hidden. e.g. if they use a class with *visibility: hidden* then your solution fails entirely, and plain JS becomes a one liner.

Comment: @RobG  - `$("<p>"+htmlString+"</p>").children(":hidden").html("");` there, the below solution in a one liner. your argument is invalid.

Comment: @Banana—you missed the point entirely. Firstly, that doesn't necessarily work at all, you don't know how the cells are hidden, the OP hasn't said. Secondly, the one–liner comment was in regard do "*simpler as compared to native JS*", which it isn't necessarily. And thirdly, that seems to resolve to `<table></table>` even if no cells are hidden (IOW, it doesn't work).

Comment: @RobG, you are the one missing the point my friend, it doesnt matter how the cells/elements are hidden. the point was to use jquery to remove them, im sure the OP can figure out how to target them regardless of the way they are hidden (and if not, he can just post back for more clarification). and i got your one-liner point, i just presented a counter argument because you seem keen on arguing :)

Comment: @Banana—perhaps you'd like to post an answer that works then.

Comment: @RobG, without seeing OP's code, ArinCool's answer is a good enough blind answer for me. he could easily adjust it if OP shares some code.

Comment: Hi all, First of all thank you for your suggested answers. I tried the above solutions, but it not my Solutions. I have table having some th and td elements with style="display:none". I just want to remove that tags only and get remaining html

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery, you can do something like this:

```
var htmlString = '<<your innerHTML string>>';    
var obj = jQuery(htmlString);
var jQ = jQuery("<p>").append(obj);
jQ.children(":hidden").html("");
var newHtml = jQ.html();
```

Now use the `newHtml` in your code.

Comment: this might ruin the report layout. better clear the hidden element's inner html `jQ.children(":hidden").html("")`

Comment: @Banana agreed!! Updated my answer

Comment: This might clear the content of a hidden cell, but the cell will still be in the table, won't it? It's also a bit hit and miss, as cells with `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` will not be cleared as they aren't selected by `:hidden`.

Comment: yes it will. as per op's requirements he needs to "remove the hidden tags' data"

Comment: Note: "*The issue is that, innerHTML data contains hidden tags as well*" which indicates to me that the entire element needs to be removed, otherwise there will (most likely) be a column of empty cells in the spread sheet.

Comment: he provides the innerHTML of the tables. which contain the hidden tags, and his only request is to remove the hidden tag's data. it will be the same if he removes the whole cell or just its content, but it might, depending on the way he generates his report, mess the report layout if some cells are missing. without seeing his code it is hard to determine the best approach, i think op should just choose what suits him best.

Comment: Yes, I would leave the decision to OP.

Comment: BTW, this answer removes the entire content of the table at `var obj = jQuery(htmlString)`.

Comment: Hi all, First of all thank you for your suggested answers. I tried the above solutions, but it not my Solutions. I have table having some th and td elements with style="display:none". I just want to remove that tags only and get remaining html.

Comment: I am using excellentexport.js in which I have to provide the innerHTML for generating Excell file.